# Apply tilt to my rotating earth

Tags: animation, graph-editor

As you can see I am animating planets revolving around a clock but I wish to emulate the earths axial tilt whilst it spins but I cannot find a way to do so. What I get is weird wobble spin. How do you suggest should I do this?

[image]

additional info: that planet is parented to an empty and the empty follows a bezier circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to move the cursor to the center (This would be the location of the clock).

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > **Mesh** > **UV Sphere**

Offset the sphere along an axis (I used <kbd>Y</kbd> in **Top View**).

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > **Empty** (Adding an **Empty** to the center).

Select your sphere > <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> > **Cursor to selected**. To move the cursor to the sphere.

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > **Empty .001** (Adding an Empty to the Sphere).

Select **Sphere** Select the **Empty.001** in the sphere > <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> > **Object**

Select that same **Empty.001** > Select the Empty in the center > <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> > **Object**

Animate rotation of **Empty.001** in the center

Animate rotation of **Empty** in **Sphere**

Rotate **Empty** in **Sphere** to tilt the sphere

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by offset the sphere along the axis?

Comment: @RQ-3D Move it away from the center. IE Grab "Y" 3

Comment: @RQ-3D I made an edit to the 5th step "Select your sphere > Shift + “S” > Cursor to selected. To move the cursor to the sphere." Sorry for any confusion here. I also added an image...

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am misunderstanding your question. You should be able to just tilt the earth and then rotate it setting keyframes how fast you want to do it. It should still follow the parent.

Dont do anything to the parent just set keyframes on the earth itself by rotating Z space. Not sure what the wobble is, check the graph editor to make sure nothing looks weird there. Maybe apply scale <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>. Make sure you dont have to many keyframes that is making it look weird.

[image]